# Apache2.4 require ip not working as expected

Tags: apache-2.4, openvpn, centos7

I want to restrict access of admin page on my Apache server. Here is my solution. I set up an openvpn server on the same server. I am connecting to server using openvpn from my client. Server status page is working as expected. However Location for /admin page gives 403 forbidden even when I am connected to vpn. I checked my external and internal ip of client. External ip is exactly the server's ip, internal ip is 10.8.0.0/24. Why I am getting 403 while server-status is working? What am I missing?

## Versions:

**Apache**: httpd-2.4.6-67.el7.centos.6.x86_64

**Os**: CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core)

**Openvpn**: openvpn-2.4.4-1.el7.x86_64

Here are the configuration files.

## Openvpn server.conf

```
# Configure server mode and supply a VPN subnet
# for OpenVPN to draw client addresses from.
# The server will take 10.8.0.1 for itself,
# the rest will be made available to clients.
# Each client will be able to reach the server
# on 10.8.0.1. Comment this line out if you are
# ethernet bridging. See the man page for more info.
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

## /etc/httpd/conf.d/project.tld.conf

```
<VirtualHost 10.8.0.1:8081>
  ServerName aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd # server's external ip
  ServerAdmin admin@project.tld 

  <Location /server-status>
    SetHandler server-status
    Require ip 10.8.0.0/24
  </Location>
 </VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.8.0.1 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:80>
  ServerName aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
  ServerAdmin admin@project.tld
  Redirect permanent / https://aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.8.0.1 aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd:443>
  ServerName aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd
  ServerAdmin admin@project.tld

  Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=31536000;"
  Header always set X-XSS-Protection "1; mode=block"
  Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

  LoadModule wsgi_module modules/mod_wsgi.so

  # Here is the problem
  <Location /admin>
    Require ip 10.8.0.0/24
    Require ip aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd/32
  </Location>

  # Aliases
  Alias /robots.txt /home/user/www/project.tld/statics/robots.txt
  Alias /statics /home/user/www/project.tld/statics
  <Directory /home/user/www/project.tld/statics>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  <Directory /home/user/www/project.tld/project>
    <Files wsgi.py>
      Require all granted
    </Files>
  </Directory>

  WSGIDaemonProcess project.tld python-path=/home/user/www/project.tld/venv/bin:/home/user/www/project.tld/venv/lib64/python3.6/site-packages
  WSGIProcessGroup project.tld
  WSGIScriptAlias / /home/user/www/project.tld/project/wsgi.py

  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/self_signed.crt
  SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/self_signed.key

  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
</VirtualHost>
```

## /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

```
Listen 80
Listen 8081

ServerName aaa.bbb.ccc.ddd # server’s external ip
ServerSignature Off
ServerTokens Prod

DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
```

Log entries:

From `/var/log/httpd/access_log`

```
10.8.0.6 - - [11/Jan/2018:14:49:08 +0200] "GET /server-status HTTP/1.1" 200 4800 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/63.0.3239.132 Safari/537.36"
```

From `/var/log/httpd/error_log` client ip is my external ip provided by ISP

```
[Thu Jan 11 14:49:15.085377 2018] [authz_core:error] [pid 28161] [client aaa.bbb.ccc.xxx:59536] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /home/user/www/project.tld/project/wsgi.py
```

Comment: you are going blind if you don't set show the documentroot. Specifically because Location can override anything you set in a directory. If you want precise help try to not mask so many directory names and include the documentroot so we can distinguish where is every item. Also servernames are important, you can mask them, but use fake names better because if you are using "xxxx.xxxx.xxxx.xxxx" and it results you use the same name in every virtualhost, you will just land in the first virtualhost always.

Comment: To be much clear; I masked external ips and directory names more clearly as you suggested.

Comment: we need to know where the documentroot is pointing

Comment: Also, make sure to define specific log files for each virtualhost, so really know where your requests are landing, at least to debug the issue.

Comment: I've separated log files, error log is collected for last virtualhost which is access of Location /admin is restricted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer my own question, someone with similar configuration can solve his problem as well. According to my research; if the apache and open VPN servers are on the same machine. Client connects to VPN and tries to access web server using server's public ip, then the traffic is not sent over the VPN, that's why I was seeing my ISP's public ip at log files. In order to access web server via VPN tunnel, it should be accessed by server's internal ip. To fix my problem, I just separated 2nd virtual host which was redirecting http traffic to https over public ip and the problem is gone.